# Paso de parámetros a una ventana modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, jsp

Buen día estoy intentando hacer una ventana modal con bootstrap a la cual le intento pasar un valor numérico ya lo he conseguido pero el valor esta siendo asignado a un input, quisiera asignarlo a una variable para poder hacer una consulta con esa variable

Así mando llamar a la ventana modal

```
<center><a href="#" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ver</a>
```

Esta es la ventana modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                    <input type="text" name="lista" id="lista"/>

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>

            </div><!-- modal content -->
        </div><!-- modal dialog -->
    </div><!-- modal fade -->
<!-- Cierra Modal -->
```

y los parámetros los asigno mediante una funcion de JavaScript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {    
     var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data().id;
      $(e.currentTarget).find('#lista').val(id);
  });
});
</script>
```

todo funciona perfectamente pero me gustaría guardar el parametro en una variable dentro de la ventana modal para posteriormente hacer una consulta  a base de datos, alguna idea ? gracias

Comment: El modal no es una página a parte, es parte de la misma página en que la llamas, no necesitas pasarle nada, lo que pases a la vista principal también está disponible en el modal.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que intento ocupar la ventana modal para visualizar una lista  estilo facebook con los likes que tiene una publicación en la pagina principal indico el numero de likes pero si deseas ver a quienes les gusta esa publicacion se despliega la ventana  modal por ello necesito pasar un parámetro para identificar el id de la publicación a la que quieren acceder

Comment: Toda esa información de cuál es la publicacion y cuantos y a quienes les gusta, necesitas pasarla a tu página principal, que asume es una lista de publicaciones. De lo contrario lo que planteas es un modal AJAX. Pero actualmente lo que muestras aquí es un modal simple.

Comment: Podrías agregar un campo de tipo Hidden en tu modal, asignarle un valor y recuperarlo desde tu JavaScript. Espero sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Mira yo uso este código para cargar un parámetro desde el botón:

```
function consulta(id)
        { 
            $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            cache: false,
            url : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx.php', //Here you will fetch records 
            data : {id_ticket:id}, //Pass $id
            success : function(data){
            $('#consulta').html(data).modal("");

        }
    });
   };
```

Cuando pulsas el boton, sí envia el valor.

El único problema que tengo es que no me abre el modal, sin embargo en la herramienta de `firefox` para depurar me indica que sí recibe el valor y realiza la consulta (`Mysql`), mas no me carga el modal en pantalla, incluso se opaca la pantalla, y por lo general me coloca dentro del botón el contenido del modal con los datos cargados desde la BD.

Answer (score 1):

De esta mannera lo hago yo, el código HTML y JavaScript está basado en Vue, sólo debes cambiar tu manera de pensar las cosas. Por ejemplo, en Vue usamos:

```
@click="store(replys)"
```

dentro del HTML, en JavaScript lo hacemos de esta manera:

```
onclick="store(replys)"
```

En el código encontrarás **`showCreateThanksYouForm`** a esa function le pasarás los valores que necesitas de esta forma:

```
<!--Button modal-->

<button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-addon btn-info waves-effect" onclick="showCreateThanksYouForm(valor)">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">
    </i>
    Agradecer
</button>
```

`ShowCreateThanksYouForm` se encargará de llamar la ventana modal que es esta:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-create-thanks-you" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button " class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    ¡Dale las gracias!
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    Ahora te toca a ti:
                </p>
                <p>
                    Por favor, recuerda que esto es solo un agradecimiento, el profesional no podrá responder a este comentario
                </p>
                <div v-if="form.errors.message">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ form.errors.message }}</div>
                </div>
                <!-- Create Client Form -->
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <textarea v-model="form.body" class="md-input" rows="4"></textarea>
                            <div class="m-t" v-if="form.errors.errors">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ form.errors.errors.body }}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Actions -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="store(replys)">
                    Agradecer.
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- End Modal Actions -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Modal Content -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Modal Dialog -->
</div>
<!-- End Modal -->
```

Este es el código JavaScript completo.

**`$('#modal-create-thanks-you').modal('show')`** esta parte se encargará de abrir tu modal mediante el id, al cargar el modal cargará la var `valor` con dichos valores ya sean objetos o en array.

```
<!--Js para llamar a la ventana modal-->

showCreateThanksYouForm (valor) {
    var valor = valor;
    $('#modal-create-thanks-you').modal('show')
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Los valores que tiene el modal son accesibles dentro de la página en la cual te encuentras, ya que lo único que hace es desplegar un div con una animación (en pocas palabras). Si de lo contrario, es llamado foráneamente, es decir que el modal esté como por ejemplo en un iframe tendrías que hacer uso de **parent**, esto para acceder a la página padre del iframe.

Ahora, lo de la consulta a la base de datos tiene que hacer uso de **AJAX**, para hacer la consulta al servidor.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {    
     var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data().id;
      $(e.currentTarget).find('#lista').val(id);
```

dentro de este codigo, agregas

```
 $.ajax({                        
           type: "POST",                 
           url: 'action/demo.php',                     
           //dataType: 'json', 
           data: { id: id }, 
           success: function(data)             
           {
               var dato= "mi id es---" + data;
               $("#lista").val(dato)
           }
       });
```

y ahí haces lo q gustes en tu bd...

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

yo uso esto...
si pasa la variable el problema que yo tengo es que tengo que usar 1 variable por "botón", mi intención era que en el onlcik asignara un valor a la variable `$nodo`, tengo 47 botones (áreas) por lo que che tenido que poner 47 modales, intenté con php self y nada, no recibo el valué

```
<div class="text-center" align="center">
  <h2>Mapa interactivo Beta</h2>
</div>

<p>
  <img id="shapes" name="usaMap" src="images/MapaNodoGral_2.png" usemap="#shapes_map" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
</p>

<map name="shapes_map">

  <area onclick="<?php $nodo1=1; ?>" name="nodo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" alt="Nodo 1" title="Nodo 1" coords="400,210,21" shape="circle" data-group="inner-circle">

  <area onclick="<?php $nodo2=2; ?>" name="nodo"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" alt="Nodo 2" title="Nodo 2" coords="430,129,22" shape="circle" data-group="inner-circle">

    </map>
```

div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">

```
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Nodo &nbsp; <?php echo $nodo1; ?>  &nbsp;&nbsp;  PERIODO:  01/04/2016 - 15/04/2016</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>
          <?php

                    $query = "SELECT num_nodo, AVG(precio_marginal), MIN(precio_marginal), MAX(precio_marginal), STD(precio_marginal) FROM muesta where num_nodo= $nodo1 "; 
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "PROMEDIO PRECIO MARGINAL: "."&nbsp;&nbsp;". $row['AVG(precio_marginal)'];
                    echo "<br />";    
                    echo "MAXIMO PRECIO MARGINAL: "."&nbsp;&nbsp;". $row['MAX(precio_marginal)'];
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo "MINIMO PRECIO MARGINAL: "."&nbsp;&nbsp;". $row['MIN(precio_marginal)'];
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo "DESVIACION ESTANDARL: "."&nbsp;&nbsp;". $row['STD(precio_marginal)'];
                    }
            ?>      
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <form method="POST"  action="reportes_graficos/ejemplo6.php" target="descripcion" > 

             <input type="hidden" name="nodo" value="<?php echo $nodo1; ?>" />
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"  value="Generar Grafica" onclick="" >

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  data-dismiss="modal" onclick="smoothScroll(document.getElementById('iframe'))">Click Me!</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
            <?php var_dump ($nodo1); ?>

        </form>   
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago de esta forma:

- Ejecuto una funcion al dar click a un botton y paso el id

---

```
<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm'
onclick='editar_modal(".$row['id'].")'><span
style='color:orange;font-weight:bold' class='fas fa-user-edit'></span>
Modificar</button></td>
```

- de la funcion genero los valores por ajax  y relleno los campos del
  modal, al final muestro el modal desde js

---

```
function editar_modal(id){
  var id=id;
  $.ajax({      
      data: {id: id},
      url: 'paginas/usuarios/admin_editar_usuario_valores.php',
      type: 'get',
      dataType : "json",
      async: false,
      error: function(X){
            alert("ha ocurrido un error");            
        },
      success: function(respuesta){         
        /*alert(respuesta.bandera);*/
        if(respuesta.bandera){
          document.getElementById('form_nombre_editar').value=respuesta.nombre;
          document.getElementById('form_correo_editar').value=respuesta.correo;
          document.getElementById('form_pass_editar').value="";
          /*document.getElementById('form_estado_editar').value=respuesta.estado;*/
          document.getElementById('form_tipo_editar').value=respuesta.tipo;
          $("#editarUsuarioModal").modal("toggle");   
        }
      }
    });  
 }
```

- el modal

---

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editarUsuarioModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Editar usuario.</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail4">Correo</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="form_correo_editar" placeholder="Correo" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="inputPassword4">Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="form_pass_editar" placeholder="Dejar en blanco si no quiere cambiar la contraseña.">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_nombre_editar" placeholder="Nombre completo" required>
          </div>          
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputState">Tipo de usuario</label>
              <select multiple id="form_tipo_editar" class="form-control" required>                                
                <?php             
                  $can="SELECT * FROM tipo_usuario t;";
                    if ($resultado = mysqli_query($link, $can)){
                      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"> <?php echo $row['descripcion'];?></option>  
                      <?php
                      }
                    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
                    }
                 ?> 
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputState">Estado</label>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                  Activo
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                  Second default radio
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="editar_usuario_guardar_btn">Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```